# What might cause `git pull` to fail seeing remote changes?

Tags: git, merge, atlassian-sourcetree, pull

**In what circumstances might the `git pull origin master` command result in a different working copy state than `git checkout master` -> `git pull` -> `git checkout feat-a` -> `git merge master` ?**

The long story.

I have a feature branch, lets call it `feat-a`. I am the only developer working on this branch. The branch was created from `master` branch. Both branches have remote origins, `origin/feat-a` and `origin/master`. Nothing special, your typical git repository arrangement.

Today I wanted to update my feature branch from remote `master`. From earlier communication with other developers, I knew there will be conflicting changes when I merge remote `master` into my feature branch.

I'm using SourceTree. So, with `feat-a` branch checked out, I opened context menu on origin/master branch and picked `Pull origin/master into current branch`. I was shocked to see Git reporting that my branch is already up-to-date. I knew it's not right, there must be changes on remote `master` branch. I repeated the command a few times. Always got the same up-to-date message.

To be 100% sure, I did it "the long way". I checked out `master` branch, clicked `Pull` button. The branch got updated with the latest commits. Then I checked out `feat-a` branch and then pulled context menu on master branch and picked `Merge master into current branch`. Voila! Here was the merge conflict I expected to get!

This got me puzzled. I had assumed that performing `pull` from `origin/master` into my current branch is the same as checking out `master`, pulling, checking out the other branch and then merging `master` into the current branch (with exception that pulling from remote `master` into another branch does not update my local `master`, but that shouldn't affect this issue).

Essentially, for some reason `pull` command from `origin/master` into `feat-a` was trying to convince me that there are no changes on `origin/master`, and only the long way with switching branches and manual merging worked as expected.

I'm not sure if SourceTree is doing something special which might affect this issue.

Comment: I too faced this issue yesterday while pulling code from Github `master branch` into my `heroku branch` in local machine but it said your branch is up-to-date, and then followed the steps what you have mentioned above. I thought that it must  have been a bug.

Comment: Verify your tracking is what you think. `git branch -avv` will show you what remote branches are tracked for each local branch. You may find that somehow `master` is tracking something other than `origin/master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you use Sourcetree, so I guess you didn't actually type `git pull origin master` on the command line. My guess is it is either something confusing in the GUI message, or a bug in Sourcetree.

I'd rather ask to the Sourcetree developpers.

Comment: Yes, this might be the case. I experienced the issue today after I updated SourceTree. I haven't had such issues earlier, so this might indeed be some new bug in SourceTree. I'll try to reproduce it today.

Comment: You were right. I - and some of my colleagues - became victims of this bug: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-4329  I guess that's the price for trusting GUI tools too much.